# php error_log() not working while hitting my file through teminal

Tags: php

I am using two files (test1.php and test2.php)

In test1.php having multi_curl code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "test2.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
```

And in the second (test2.php) I am put the error_log() for creating the log.

```
error_log('test message', 3, ABSPATH.'error_log12.txt');
```

When, I am hitting the first file through browser it'll create correct log into define location but when, I am hitting first file through terminal it will not create that log.

Please anyone suggest me, what was the reason behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your platform, version, and possibly the phase of the moon, PHP can maintain several php.ini files for various invocation methods, including CLI, FPM, and whatever other adapters you may have installed. I would expect the file you're not explicitly setting error logging in to behave in whatever way those respective ini files define, so that's the first place I'd look.

Comment: I didn't get your point, my concern is that while I am hitting that file through browser it works fine and not working when i am hitting through terminal.

Comment: To be more clear: PHP usually creates several configuration files. One is used when you run a script from the command line, and another may be invoked when you run the same script through your browser. So while it's the same script, it does make a difference *how* it's being run, because those configuration files can define different ways of handling error logging.

Comment: Yes, I understood but how can i identify what server is not running while i am using terminal. Is there any way??

Comment: When you run a script via the terminal, i.e. `php scriptname.php`, PHP uses its CLI configuration file (on my system that's /etc/php5/cli/php.ini). When you run it through a web server, PHP uses its configuration file for whatever that web server is; on my system, using php5-fpm, that's /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini. These are different configuration files that can have different error logging settings.